# Unable to execute BatchUpdate across multiple table table insert using spring boot jdbctemplate and oracle( ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended)

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

Unable to insert multiple tables at a time using jdbctemplate in spring boot and oracle.While executing application throwing "java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"

Getting Below Exception:

```
2022-04-13 20:45:06.135 TRACE 18712 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils      : Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 14, parameter value [JEE002], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type unknown
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [insert into FILE(ID, NAME,CONTENTS,CREATED_ON,CREATED_BY,MODIFIED_ON,MODIFILED_BY) values(?,?,?,sysdate,?,sysdate,?);insert into JOB(ID,SHORT_NAME,DESCRIPTION,FILE_ID,OCR_ID,PRIMARY_SKILL_SET,SUB_SKILL_SET,CREATED_ON,CREATED_BY,MODIFIED_ON,MODIFILED_BY)  values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,sysdate,?,sysdate,?); ]; nested exception is java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

The above exception getting while running application. Here I am trying to insert multiple tables at the same time.

Comment: INSERT ALL should be used for multi table INSERT. Refer on using INSERT ALL here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29469456/oracle-insert-all-with-select-giving-invalid-specification-error

Comment: That's not true, @Pankaj. INSERT ALL works well with a single table. As of the original question, I can't comment it, I don't know Java.

Comment: I believe, like using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`, the prepared statement must be either a single SQL command or a single anonymous block - it shouldn't be stringing together multiple commands with `;`. That's why the error says `SQL command not properly ended`.

Answer (score 0):

Your statements look fine. Can you try wrapping both inserts into a begin-end block:

```
BEGIN
insert into FILE(ID, NAME,CONTENTS,CREATED_ON,CREATED_BY,MODIFIED_ON,MODIFILED_BY) 
          values(? , ?   ,?       ,sysdate   ,?         ,sysdate    ,?);
insert into JOB(ID,SHORT_NAME,DESCRIPTION,FILE_ID,OCR_ID,PRIMARY_SKILL_SET,SUB_SKILL_SET,CREATED_ON,CREATED_BY,MODIFIED_ON,MODIFILED_BY) 
        values (? ,?         ,?          ,?      ,?     ,?                ,?            ,sysdate   ,?         ,sysdate    ,?);
END;
```